# Footer lines inconveniently positioned when editing from the first posts review queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, review

The footer line is misbehaving again and overlapping the edit preview when editing a post from the "First Posts" review queue (possibly others?)

This is from Chrome 28 on Linux:

> [image]

This from Firefox 17 (first question). Both on Linux.

> [image]

Windows Vista/IE 10:

> [image]

The bottom of the page looks a bit naked when that happens.

Comment: Chrome 28 is beta, and therefore not supported. However I did reproduce the bug on Chrome 26.0.1410.64m (current stable) on Win7.

Comment: Ouch, forgot to check and I had updated earlier today (and my Firefox is way too old apparently). Added a screenshot from IE 10 on Vista, doesn't look too browser-specific.

Comment: can you still repro this? we pushed a fix for it yesterday.

Comment: @Jin: can't repro on Chrome 27 or Firefox 20 on Vista, the footer line's just where it should be. (I'm travelling and that's all I have available except IE8, and that's... eeek!) Since that din't look very browser-sensitive, seems [status-completed]. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing a little `clear: both;` couldn't fix. Thanks for the report.